# How to uninstall gcc 4.6.2 installed from source?

Tags: gcc

I have gcc 4.6.2 installed (installed from tar source) in my ubuntu server 10.10 64 bit, I have also installed gcc 4.4.5. I want to uninstall gcc 4.6.2 and make my old gcc 4.4.5 default. How can I do this?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/663788/uninstall-gcc-from-source || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303928/how-to-uninstall-gcc-installed-from-source

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to uninstall `4.6.2`. If you have installed it from the repositories and also have gcc 4.5 installed, you can do:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

which will allow you to choose what is your default compiler.  Uninstalling `gcc 4.6.2` could impact other packages.

Answer (score 0):

First, *don't* change the default compiler used by your OS super-user. The packaging guys have carefully tested that everything works with 4.6, and if you change that you risk destabilizing your system, and that could end badly.

What you can do is adjust the default compiler for yourself only by simply altering the PATH variable in your shell setup.

So, simply add this:

```
PATH=/path/to/your/gcc/bin:$PATH
```

to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` or whatever is most appropriate to you. (Or just add it to all of them to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

In GCC 5.1.0, the best method so far is to install it somewhere else with `DESTDIR` and then use that to decide which files were generated, as mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25304014/895245

Although there is no top-level `uninstall` target, some directories do have it, in particular `gcc`, so you can do:

```
cd build/gcc
sudo make uninstall
```

This does not remove everything that was installed, but it removes major executables like `gcc`, `g++`, `cpp`... contained in that directory, so it might be enough.

Another dirty workaround:

```
sudo find /usr/local/bin -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1 -delete
```