# GCC related issue(Need to install latest version of GCC 4.9.0)

Tags: gcc

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I want to install latest version of GCC 4.9.0. Is it possible to uninstall default GCC compiler prepacked with OS?

In this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101471/how-to-uninstall-gcc-4-6-2), I read that uninstalling the default compiler may lead to stability issues Since I am planning to install the latest version, will that cause stability issue?

And another problem is that in the official GNU GCC page, I read that GCC supports compiling of c++ programs. But I couldn't compile a program using gcc. So, I used g++. By using g++ instead of GCC, It gave an error stating that g++ is not installed. Wouldn't Ubuntu come along with g++ or is there any other config to use g++ with GCC?

Comment: Running `sudo apt-get install g++` will install g++ 4.8.

Comment: I have downloaded the source tarball of GCC 4.9.0 from ftp server of gnu site. Is there a way to replace the existing gcc using this tarball file?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build from sources gcc-4.9 (latest version is 4.9.1), here is a good, step by step, description of how to build and install gcc-4.9.1 on Ubuntu 14.04:

https://solarianprogrammer.com/2014/08/26/building-gcc-on-ubuntu-linux/

A short resume of what you need to do, please check the above link for more details:

- Install build-essentials, gawk, m4, gcc-multilib
- Download the source code for GMP, MPC, MPFR, GCC
- Build and install them in this order (see the link for details):

  - GMP
  - MPFR
  - MPC
  - GCC

After that you should be able to invoke gcc-4.9.1, g++-4.9.1 and gfortran-4.9.1 from the Terminal.

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer. Please have a look at the link I've posted, basically it is an entire article. Do you want me to copy/paste this article here ?

Comment: No, just telling the essential parts is fine - which you probably did in the meantime.